# What can I use from AD (via LDAP) as an user-specific encryption key?

Tags: perl, security, encryption, ldap

I'm using Perl/MySQL/Apache to make a small internal information-sharing app.  There will be users with different security levels, and many of those users are likely to have root/admin privileges to the host server and other parts of our network.

I had originally designed something like this:

A master key would be used to encrypt all the content, but obviously I don't want this key stored in plain-text (in code, nor the DB), so there would be a Keys table where each user's public key is used to encrypt a copy of the cipher.  If for some reason the master key should need to be changed, the key copies could all be regenerated and no data would be lost.

Each user would have an entry in the Users table, with their password and their private key encrypted with a hash of their plain-text password.  On login, the text would be used to decrypt and compare with the stored encrypted password to verify identity, then to decrypt the private key, stored on the server in a session variable until logout.

What I would like to do is use AD authentication via LDAP instead of a local password for all but the Admin user.  But, since the users' passwords could change between logins, I can't rely on that as cipher text to encrypt/decrypt the private keys.

So my question is this:  What is a reasonably secure piece of private data I can use from AD as a cipher?  I don't want this to be apparent to anyone with access to AD Users & Computers or the like, though I would of course have to be able to get this info from a server process somehow.  (Maybe through user impersonation?)

Any other ideas or gaping holes in this process?  I know the server process potentially could be exploited to dump memory contents, or a root user might be able to read the same through raw access, but that is acceptable risk.  Ultimately anyone with root or physical access is generally trustworthy.  Nonetheless, I want the database contents encrypted to keep honest folks honest.

Comment: Why not just use AD/LDAP group membership to manage access to the data?

Comment: It isn't access control I'm concerned with.  I need something to use as an encryption key that wouldn't be possible to retrieve without the user's credentials.  AD has certificates and such, and NTFS encrypts local data with a host key, then encrypts that key with an user key.  That's the approach I would like to take.  So where to get that key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is simply not possible with default AD configuration. By default all users have full read access in the naming partition of AD (where all user objects are stored), furthermore it is also possible to configure AD to allow anonymous users the same read access. AD is not designed to store private data, basically it is as private as a phone-book.

If your AD has default configuration and you are happy with the fact that every authenticated user can read the data, you should be able to use any attribute which cannot be changed by any trivial means.

For example you can use objectSid, which contains the user's SID in binary or objectGUID, which contains its globally unique object identifier.

However the objectSid attribute can be changed when the SID of the user is changed - there is a TechNet article titled "SID vs. GUID" describing in which scenarios objectSid can be changed - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961625.aspx.