# How can we support ADFS if we *require* a shared secret for encryption?

Tags: security, encryption, adfs

**EDIT: (summary)**: I'm looking first for a way to have a custom, user-specific attribute passed to us as part of the ADFS signon; if that's reasonable, I'll dig into how to secure it.

**EDIT: (clarification)**: I don't want to pass something through AD at time of login -- if the user has to enter their password and *then* authenticate again against AD, they're going to end up with confusing, mis-matching passwords.  Instead I want registration with us to go like this:

1. user enters details (email, etc)
2. we generate a long random string, encrypt it, then provide that as part of a unique id to the client's AD

Then at each login:

1. We redirect the user to the client's AD for auth
2. Once the user is authorized, they're redirected back to us with user & claim info
3. That info includes the unique ID we generated -- so we extract a user ID and decrypt the password from that.

This would be lower security than we normally offer, but it's the best I can imagine if AD is involved.  Is this possible?

**Long version**: A customer is asking that we add support for single sign-on to our web application, implementing Microsoft ADFS (Active Directory Federated Services).

The problem is that we rely on the user's password to decrypt their record; their private key is encrypted with their password, so we can't access their record without the password.

I've been digging into the documentation, e.g., http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx -- but currently I don't see way to securely manage some kind of secret encryption key using AD FS.

It wouldn't have to be the password itself, of course -- we implemented OAuth2 by generating random access tokens that have the same properties as a password (can be used to decrypt the user's record)... but an incoming, authenticated user needs to come with **some** kind of secure, private token.

Any guidance much appreciated!

Comment: I found a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416282/what-can-i-use-from-ad-via-ldap-as-an-user-specific-encryption-key?rq=1 -- it suggests that it's unwise to store any sensitive data in AD, because it's simply not designed to be secure.  At this point I'm looking for how to get a custom per-user attribute passed to our server at time of AD signin, then I'll sort out if there's a way this can be secure even if AD doesn't store it securely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADFS 2.0, you can [customize the pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895355.aspx).

So you could e.g. take the password, mangle it, write it to AD before invoking the SignIn and then have a claims rule that passes this. Then reverse the process in your application.

Note - I'm not suggesting that this is a "good" solution - just an example of what you can do.

Obviously security needs to be paramount!

Comment: Thanks, this is a start -- I've updated the question as well to reflect that first I should figure out a clean way to pass a custom, user-specific attribute back to us with the AD signin; next I can dig into how to secure that.  Your link mentions a "custom attribute store" as well as custom pages -- is that a better way to go?

Comment: A "custom attribute store" in that context is some store that isn't AD / SQL / LDAP which are the stores that ADFS supports. I don't see that it would be any more secure than AD?

Comment: Oh, reading the other response I suddenly understand that you're talking about prompting the user for a password, and passing that through.  I've added clarifications to my question to explain the flow I think can work.

Comment: Just to be clear - when a user registers with you do they already have an entry in the client's AD or is this created as part of your registration process?

Comment: In most cases, these users will already have an entry in the client's AD; that's what makes this tricky...  When the user registers with us, I'm seeking a way to add info (somehow) to the client's AD that will be returned to us each time the user signs in.  We have support from the client's IT staff, if they may need to configure something... I just haven't yet found how this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is Two ways to get your problem solved.

1. Customize the ADFS SignOn page(you should anyways take a backup) to create a form that receives users password. It is an webforms aspx page so you should have no trouble doing it. From there you must build your own STS to issue claims to ADFS so that ADFS can in turn pass these to your relying party. Map the custom STS as attribute store to the ADFS
2. You are just doing things wrong by taking security in your hand. ADFS uses HTTPS for transport level security and secure encryption with SAML 2.0 to handle your information, so another encryption would be no-brainer.

let me know which way you like going

Comment: For these users, I'd like to rely on ADFS for authentication, but still store a long random string in AD (linked to that user's account with us, and encrypted for security) that would replace the password in our encryption.  How do I store a unique string per-user in our client's AD when each user signs up with us?  Bonus points if there's a way to update this in the future, as well... passwords should be changed now and again.